# How can TabNavigator child screen refer to parent StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

The structure of the application is this.

- StackNavigator

  - StackA-Screen(TabNavigator)

    - TabChildA-Screen
    - TabChildB-Screen
    - ...
  - StackB-Screen

code in `App.js`

```
const TabComponent = TabNavigator(
{
    TabChildA-Screen: {
    screen: TabChildA,
    },
    TabChildB-Screen: {
    screen: TabChildB,
    }
},
{
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false
}
);

const StackComponent = StackNavigator(
{
    StackA-Screen: {
    screen: TabComponent,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerBackTitle: null,
        headerRight: (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("StackB-Screen", { space: "" }) // can't navigate to "StackB-Screen".
            }
        >
            <MaterialIcon
            name="playlist-add"
            size={Sizes.NavigationBar.Icon.Size}
            style={{ padding: 8, color: Colors.White }}
            />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    })
    },
    StackB-Screen: {
    screen: StackB,
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: "StackA-Screen",
    mode: "modal"
}
);

export default StackComponent;
```

I want to navigate `TabChildA-Screen` to `StackB-Screen`.
But, `TabChildA-Screen` can refer to `navigator` is `navigator` of `TabNavigator`.

code in `TabChildA-Screen`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

class StackB extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
    <View
        style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
        }}
    >
        <Button
        onPress={ () =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate("StackB-Screen") // can't navigate to "StackB-Screen".
        }
        title="move to StackB-Screen"
        />
    </View>
    );
}
}

export default StackB;
```

How to `TabChildA-Screen`refer `StackNavigator` ?

Comment: Please add your navigation create code and please add any error messages if you are getting. Check [mcve] for asking better questions.

Comment: Sorry. Question updated.